# Multi sample chi-square distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a question from my assignment.

> For a total of 150 households selected randomly from 3 cities -- A, B and C -- of 50 each, the sample mean and covariance matrices are as below:
>
> For A,
>
> Mean = $\begin{pmatrix}
>         90\
>         40\\
>         \end{pmatrix}$'
>
> S = $\begin{pmatrix}
>         25 & 0\\
>         0 & 25 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}$
>
> For B,
>
> Mean = $\begin{pmatrix}
>         100\
>         50\\
>         \end{pmatrix}$'
>
> S = $\begin{pmatrix}
>         16 & 9\\
>         9 & 9 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}$
>
> For C,
>
> Mean = $\begin{pmatrix}
>         80\
>         60\\
>         \end{pmatrix}$'
>
> S = $\begin{pmatrix}
>         19 & 1\\
>         1 & 16 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}$
>
> Based on this data, is there any significant evidence indicating the residents of the 3 cities have different household incomes and expenses? Assume  $$ -( n-1- (p+a)/ 2 ) log ⋏ \sim ^2_{p(a-1)} $$

The problem is I have no idea what "a" and "⋏" stands for. I presume ⋏ is diag( eigenvalues of the matrices).

My idea is to combine all the Mean sample into one whole and Covariance sample into another whole. There after finding $H_0$ using the distribution assumption given. However, what is my "a" and my "⋏"?

Is my thinking correct or do I have to compare A vs B, B vs C and C vs A?

Comment: I think what you have written as $⋏$ or ⋏ is actually the Greek upper case letter Lambda: $\Lambda$ and your expression looks similar to that in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks's_lambda_distribution (a rather incomplete article)